# Backman on iAPC to backup the database service running on other cloud platform (TCI)

Tags: swisscomdev

Need your help on configuring backman which is running on iAPC cloud foundry to take the backup of the MariaDB database which is running on swisscom internal Telco cloud TCI (sharedtcs.net) open-stack cluster. I need to use cloud foundry so that my backman will continue to run on iAPC. I have created S3 bucket in iAPC. I want to create a custom DB service so that my backman can connect to the DB that is on other TCI cloud to take backup and store on s3 bucket in iAPC. What changes are required in manifest.yml file in this scenario and how can I request the connectivity between iAPC and my database in Telco cloud ?

https://github.com/JamesClonk/backman/blob/master/docs/cloudfoundry/deployment.md

env:
TZ: Europe/Zurich

```
BACKMAN_USERNAME: ((username)) # optional, username for HTTP Basic Auth
BACKMAN_PASSWORD: ((password)) # optional, password for HTTP Basic Auth
# BACKMAN_ENCRYPTION_KEY: "" #  optional, data-at-rest-encryption for backups stored on S3

# consult /docs/configuration.md and /docs/cloudfoundry/configuration.md for more details on $BACKMAN_CONFIG
# please edit the "services" section below before deploying backman, those are just examples and not meant to be used!
BACKMAN_CONFIG: |
  {
    "log_level": "info",
    "logging_timestamp": false,
    "disable_web": false,
    "disable_metrics": false,
    "disable_restore": false,
    "disable_metrics_logging": false,
    "disable_health_logging": true,
    "unprotected_metrics": false,
    "unprotected_health": true,
    "s3": {
      "service_label": "dynstrg",
      "bucket_name": "dev_s3"
    },
    "services": {
      "mariadb": {
        "schedule": "0 0 2,18,22 * * *",
        "timeout": "2h",
        "retention": {
          "days": 90,
          "files": 20
        },
        "service_binding": {
          "type": "mysql",
          "provider": "mariadb",
          "host": "IP address of database",
          "username": "root",
          "password": "xxxxxx",
          "database": "router"
          "port": 5432
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have tried this BACKMAN_CONFIG but its not working